# What's the difference between opening an app from the applications screen and the recently used apps list? (android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

Can anyone tell me what the difference is between opening an app from the applications screen and opening it from that recently used apps list that pops up when you long-press the home button?

I didn't even know that recently used list existed until a friend managed to break my app by launching it from there.  He tried twice and got the same force quit, but when he launched it from the applications screen it opened fine.

The error log told me that a nullPointerException occurred in the getCount method on my ArrayAdaptor for my ListView.

Anyway I just wondered if there was a difference that I need to know about and adapt my code to deal with?

Comment: The NullPointerException occurred when you called the getCount method or the exception happened within getCount? In other words, is getCount at the end of the trace or is there more?

Comment: A couple of questions: can you reproduce this behavior, either on a real device or in an emulator? What device is your friend using? In particular, what OS level? (As I understand it, some things changed in Honeycomb regarding how a long press of home works.)

Comment: Honeycomb has its own recent apps list, thus a long press is not needed (and i do not believe brings up recent apps, I think it brings up a mini view of your homepages)

Comment: My guess is that something isn't saved in onSaveInstanceState and it's required when your activity is recreated.

Comment: Very interesting guys.  So I think my friend's phone is an OS prior to Honeycomb.  Probably 2.2.2 or somewhere around that.  I have been unable to reproduce the behavior and it's a little mysterious.  Going to take a look at the possibility of the onSaveInstantState not saving what it should, and also the idea of using the android:launchMode, as mentioned below.  Many thanks for the input and discussion!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, If your application is completely shutted down, launch from applications screen and recently used apps list should have no difference, both refresh start your application and open your application's MainActivity (by stack-push your application's MainActivity into a newly created task)

However, as Android is multi-task OS, your application can be put into background in standby mode i.e. open your application then short-press home button, this is not same as press back button. If you haven't override these key pressed in your application, press back button several times with pop all your activities off from activity stack and finally kill your application, whereas press home button will bring System's HomeActivity into foreground hence flip your application (AKA. task with activity stack) into background.

Things becomes more interesting here, depend on which value your configure your activity's [android:launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) in AndroidManifest.xml, if you use standard or singleTop:
1. launch app from recently used apps list always bring your standby activity back to foreground, i.e. re-order activity stack.
2. launch app from applications screen will create a new instance of your MainActivity and open it, i.e. push a newly created MainActivity into activity stack, so now you have two instances in your application's activity stack

If you use singleTask or singleInstance:
2. launch app from applications screen will use the standby MainActivity (if exist) in your application's activity stack and re-open it, i.e. re-order activity stack.

Checkout [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) to see how different configurations may affect your application's activity stack behaviour.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the launchMode option - thanks for pointing that out.  Will try experimenting with those different modes.  Thanks for the detailed and thoughtful input!

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any difference in how the activity is launched from history, apart from the fact that the launching Intent will have the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) set.

Comment: The question is "What's the difference between opening an app from the applications screen and the recently used apps list?" and I say that there is no such difference, other than for a flag. How is it not an answer? Agree on the request for the logcat.

Comment: No probs! Editing away the logcat request, actually that was more out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there should be no difference. These are the lifecycle methods I typically see when pressing the home button from an activity, on android 2.3.4

```
onPause
onStop
```

then when I use either the icon or previous applications to navigate back, I see

```
onRestart
onStart
onResume
```

Now, in some cases the system will tell your activity to finish while you are away (or immediately when you return if an orientation change occurred). Then you will see `onDestroy`, and the following when you navigate back

```
onCreate
onStart
onResume
```

I don't think there is anything mysterious going on here. According to the [Activity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle), there are only four states that a process can be in, and both of these fall under background activity.

Comment: Very useful to know - thank you Craigy - I'm sure this info is going to come in handy as I go forward with debugging!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to think about it. All of your activities are launched form Intents. Holding down the home button allows you to open that activity using the last intent that launched it. This can give you some unexpected results however. For instance, if you are able to launch your activity from something special like a widget.